# Does “landfill” refer only to the landfill site, or also to the material?

Tags: meaning

In particular, is it proper to say “10 tons of landfill”, or do you have to say “10 tons of landfill *waste*” or similar?

Comment: Timwi, you need to (a) look in the dictionaries of your choice; (b) report any inconsistencies here; and only then (c) ask your question.

Comment: There is the problem here that the answers to this question 'given' (suggested) by commonly-available references are dependent on which commonly-available reference is treated as the most authoritative. Perhaps we could agree to go with OED's allowed polysemes (see my comment below)?

Comment: No, you don't "have to say" _10 tons of landfill waste_ or _10 tons of landfill dirt_. The phrase _10 tons of landfill_ is fine on its own, and it is in fact found in many published works. If you peruse [this list](https://www.google.com/#q=%22tons+of+landfill%22&safe=off&start=10&tbm=bks), you'll see plenty of references that go both ways; some using _landfill waste_, or _landfill garbage_, while others simply say _tons of landfill_, and leave it to the reader to figure out what kind of landfill it is, based on surrounding context.

Comment: Just in case that link doesn't work, I'll just quote a few examples: (1) _Even after recycling, 11.8 percent of the 8 million tons of landfill is made up of plastic._ (2) _estimates calculate that meeting/convention attendees will produce nearly 730,000 tons of landfill per year._ (3) _the storms prompted the city to build a 12-mile-long, 17-foot-high seawall along the Gulf, and workers literally raised the island grade level by up to 12 feet, using tons of landfill._ The first two references seem to be using the word _landfill_ to mean "garbage"; but the third likely refers to dirt and rock.

Answer (score 4):

[Landfill](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/landfill)

If you WERE to refer to it as such, "10 tons of landfill" would roughly mean "10 tons of material stacked in layers of dirt".

The material itself CAN be referred to as "landfill" according to [an Oxford definition](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/landfill), but the prominent definition seems to be for the process and place, with its usage defining it as 'the material which is found therein' being more rare.

Comment: Sorry but downvoted this.  I asked 3 coworkers, and we all agree... Landfill is a place.  Looks like Oxford is British meaning or it needs to be updated.

Comment: Different usage in different parts of the world perhaps? I'd like to see someone with more experience in American vs. British English weigh in on this, but at the very least it does appear to be an accepted use of the word, if maybe a bit more rare. For now, I'll edit the answer to call it a more rare use of the word.

Comment: @Zibbobz - I hate downvoting... just add a little context to your region on the answer.